# What does it mean: Enum declarations can only merge with namespace or other enum declarations

Tags: typescript, enums

I got this error in my Types.ts file

> ./sharedDirectory/Types.ts:880:13 Type error: Enum declarations can
> only merge with namespace or other enum declarations.
>
> 878 | }*/   879 |
>
> > 880 | export enum InvoiceProvider {
> > |             ^   881 |   No = "-",   882 |   Billingo = "Billingo",   883 |   Szamlazzhu = "szamlazz.hu", error Command failed
> > with exit code 1.

I have following relating decaltarions:

```js
export enum InvoiceProvider { // <---- ERROR here
  No = "-",
  Billingo = "Billingo",
  Szamlazzhu = "szamlazz.hu",
}

export type SelectItemKeys =
  | InvoiceProvider
  | PaymentProviderName
  | SzamlazzhuVatKeys
  | BillingoVatKeys
  | PricingAndInvoicingType
  | InvoiceFulfillmentDate
  | InvoiceItemQuantityType;

export let selectItemList: {
  [selectItemDataOptionId: string]: SelectItemData<SelectItemKeys>;
} = {
  selectedInvoiceProvider: new SelectItemData<InvoiceProvider>(
    {
      InvoiceProvider.No: {"hu": "-", "en": "-"},
      InvoiceProvider.Billingo: {"hu": "Billingo", "en": "Billingo"},
      InvoiceProvider.Szamlazzhu: {"hu": "Szamlazz.hu", "en": "Szamlazz.hu"},
    },
    InvoiceProvider.No
  ),
};
```

I do not see what is wrong. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have any other declared types with name - `InvoiceProvider` ?

Comment: nope, I do not have

Comment: Although this doesn't apply to this `InvoiceProvider` case, I forgot to make the enum in `Pascalcase`, that's why such error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had syntax error.

You need to wrap enum property into square brackets.

```
[InvoiceProvider.No]
```

Example:

```js
export enum InvoiceProvider { 
  No = "-",
  Billingo = "Billingo",
  Szamlazzhu = "szamlazz.hu",
}
class SelectItemData{}

export type SelectItemKeys =
  | InvoiceProvider
  | PaymentProviderName
  | SzamlazzhuVatKeys
  | BillingoVatKeys
  | PricingAndInvoicingType
  | InvoiceFulfillmentDate
  | InvoiceItemQuantityType;

export let selectItemList: {
  [selectItemDataOptionId: string]: SelectItemData<SelectItemKeys>;
} = {
  selectedInvoiceProvider: new SelectItemData<InvoiceProvider>(
    {
      [InvoiceProvider.No]: {"hu": "-", "en": "-"}, // <--- [InvoiceProvider.No] in square brackets
      [InvoiceProvider.Billingo]: {"hu": "Billingo", "en": "Billingo"},
      [InvoiceProvider.Szamlazzhu]: {"hu": "Szamlazz.hu", "en": "Szamlazz.hu"},
    },
    InvoiceProvider.No
  )
}
```

If you are using computed property names, they should be wrapped into square brackets